# symfony2 date field type format option changes input type to text

Tags: date, symfony, types, format

When i do:

```
    $builder->add('submittedAt_min',
                    'date',
                    array('widget' => 'single_text', 'label' => 'my label', 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'my placeholder')));
```

i get:

```
    <input type="date" placeholder="my placeholder" required="required" name="es_app_filter[submittedAt_min]" id="es_app_filter_submittedAt_min" class="hasDatepicker">
```

The type is "date"

But when I add format option to field:

```
    $builder->add('submittedAt_min',
                    'date',
                    array('format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy', 'widget' => 'single_text', 'label' => 'my label', 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'my placeholder')));
```

I get:

```
      <input type="text" placeholder="my placeholder" required="required" name="es_app_filter[submittedAt_min]" id="es_app_filter_submittedAt_min">
```

the input type is now 'text'.

I do several things in jQuery basing on [type="date"]. When it changes to "text" all my action wont work.

Any ideas why is it this way, how to fix it, any workaround?

Comment: no solution, just workaround. I added a css class to all my fields of type date. However, I had to change my js and css. I'm still hoping for better solution.

Comment: I made a ticket at symfony bug tracker, hope it'll help. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8726

Comment: ok, thx - hope we get a solution from the bugtracker...

Comment: I got the answer from Symfony, and put in in here as well. It explains everything, but is far from satisfactory.

Answer (score 3):

So I just got answer from Symfony IssueTracker.

```
See comment here https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php#L130
The field type is set to "date" only if the format matches the one expected by HTML5 ( yyyy-MM-dd )
```

The comment is:

```
    // Change the input to a HTML5 date input if
    //  * the widget is set to "single_text"
    //  * the format matches the one expected by HTML5
    if ('single_text' === $options['widget'] && self::HTML5_FORMAT === $options['format']) {
        $view->vars['type'] = 'date';
    }
```

https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Extension/Core/Type/DateType.php#L130

**It's not a bug, it's a feature.**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting format after widget in the array (like the example on the symfony2 docs)? http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#format

Comment: It's associative array, order does not matter.